# How to remove automatic applied coupon in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, coupon-codes

I want to remove automatic applied coupon when user enter another coupon code.

Answer (score 0):

For the coupon code, go into it in the backend and check the "actions" tab. There should be a section saying "Stop further rules processing". Set that to Yes. Should fix your issue.